# Clarification on Size of an Encryption Key

Tags: keys, key-size, encoding

Given a key with a certain key size (e.g., 64bits). Would I be correct to interpret this as 8 characters (since each character would be 8 bits under ASCII encoding)?

Because the ASCII scheme is limited to just 127 characters, this would mean that characters not included in the English language are not considered. Could it be instead that 64 bits has to be interpreted based on an encoding scheme such as unicode that includes many more characters? -- This would mean that 64 bits contains a much smaller number of characters since a unicode character takes more bits.

Comment: incidentally, this is exactly why passwords need different handling than keys

Comment: Can you clarify? What exactly is the difference in treatment between the two?

Comment: key's "encoding scheme" is not unicode, it's typically hex or base64, which lets us represent any 0-255 value in a couple plain chars instead of one raw "byte". we don't usually use hex-encoded strings for entering passwords, so they need different handling. Then there's the part about password alphabets being only 90-something chars instead of 255, so we need derivation to stretch the bits while possibly sandbagging the performance to avert brute-forcing.

Comment: This means that individual bytes within a key do not necessarily map to ASCII or keyboard characters, right? But I have heard of cases where a password is used to produce a key. How is this exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Characters" is the wrong level of abstraction here, and fixating on that can only lead you astray.  **Proper cryptographic keys are not passwords!**

- Passwords are normally human-chosen, and users may be expected to memorize them.
- Cryptographic keys must **not** be human-chosen!  And no good key is human-memorable—you should generally keep keys as copies under secure storage (which may be password-protected).

Why is this so important?  Because most cryptographic algorithms expect you to choose keys **uniformly at random** from the whole range of allowed values.  For algorithms where the key is a fixed-length bit sequence, that means **any** sequence of bits of the required size should be **equally likely** as any other.

This means that to generate a cryptographic key **you must *not* ask humans to choose characters like you do for passwords**, because humans are bad at randomness.  Rather, you must use a **cryptographically secure random number generator** to produce an array of randomly-chosen raw bytes.  So to work with keys you should stay clear of any character string types that involve character encodings like ASCII or Unicode, and learn how to work with byte arrays in the programming language of your choice.  For example in Java it would be the `byte[]` type; in Rust it would be `[u8]` (byte slice) or `[u8; N]` (byte array of size `N`); in C it would be `char[]` (a type that in hindsight should have had a different name); etc.  Or even better, you should work with a type that abstracts away from this, like Java's [`KeyGenerator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.html) and [`SecretKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/SecretKey.html).

Note that keys are sometimes *serialized* as base-64 or hexadecimal ASCII string, but that's just a *format* for, e.g., sticking them into file types like JSON that can't accept arbitrary bytes.  But the algorithms want the raw byte arrays!

Also, there is something called **password-based [key derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function)**, which is the use of specialized cryptographic algorithms to turn user-selected passwords into pseudo-random cryptographic keys.  Well-designed encryption programs that work off passwords don't use the user-supplied passwords directly as keys, but rather run them through such an algorithm.  This is sometimes called "password-based encryption."  Popular algorithms for deriving keys from passwords are:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt

Note that this approach trades security for user-friendliness.  Users find passwords easier to (mis)use and (mis)understand than proper cryptographic keys, but they are very unlikely to choose passwords that are nearly as strong as a proper, randomly-generated key.  (And the very few users who choose equivalently strong passwords are likely sophisticated enough to use proper keys!)

Comment: Your mention of the java byte type leads me to the next question: In java, the byte type holds integers from -127 and 128. But keys i believe should be between 0 and 255 for each byte; which requires the same amount of memory, but with different meanings. Any comment about this?

Comment: @Minaj: That's indeed a quirk of Java's, but Java APIs that deal with unsigned bytes just pretend otherwise and implicitly treat the `byte` values' bit representations as the equivalent unsigned byte value.  Case in point, Java uses `byte[]` in the character encoding methods in `String`—see [this constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) and [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String)).

Comment: @Minaj: One catch that's worth mentioning though is that when you're implementing cryptographic algorithms that assume unsigned words you often have to do some funny stuff in Java to avoid getting bitten by the signed semantics.  For example, to convert an `int` to a `long` with unsigned semantics (i.e., just pad the `int`'s binary representation with zeroes), you can't to `(long)myInt` but rather have to do `myInt & 0x00000000ffffffffL`. [Google's Guava library has some support for this sort of operations.](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PrimitivesExplained)

Comment: In C (and C++ etc) it's better to use `unsigned char` or since 1999 the effectively equivalent but more descriptive `uint8_t`. Plain `char` may be signed or unsigned depending on the implementation, so code you tested on one system may suddenly break when moved to another. For Java yes `byte` being signed is a nuisance but at least it's consistent so you just learn to type `&0xFF` everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, 64 bits is equivalent to 8 bytes, because there are 8 bits per byte.

"Could it be instead that 64 bits has to be interpreted based on an encoding scheme such as unicode that includes many more characters? "

No - the key does not need to be encoded as either ascii or UTF. Typically crypto algorithms operate either on an array of unsigned characters, or larger words when required (i.e. unsigned long long for 64 bit words).

Comment: note: I'm not sure what your use case is where you got the encoding idea from.

Comment: Is it not possible to have a key such as "ab1234cd"? In such a case we would need a way to convert it into 1s and 0s, which calls for an encoding scheme -- thats how I got into this whole encoding idea.